# WildFly Swarm with Ghost4J throws NoClassDefFoundError: IOUtils

Tags: java, maven, wildfly, wildfly-swarm

I'm trying to use Ghost4J in a demo project and included the library in my pom.xml.

Everytime Ghost4J tries to access IOUtils of `org.apache.commons.io` a `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown although commons-io.jar is included in the fatjar generated by maven.

I already tried putting `org.apache.commons.io` in a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` like this

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.3">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.io" export="true" services="export"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I pushed the code to GitHub: https://github.com/crumohr/swarm-ghost4j

Comment: Is the jar for commons-io in WEB-INF/lib? That's one problem.

I think jboss-deployment-structure.xml not working is because of https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SWARM-1051

Comment: Yes, the library is in there. The issue you found seems to cause my problem, I'll attach my error to that ticket. Thanks for your research!